# MikTeX Console cannot check for updates with error message below

Tags: errors, miktex, miktex-update

MiKTeX Problem Report

Message: The package definition file could not be parsed.

Data: path="C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\mik19571\cellprops.tpm", column="1124", line="2"

---

BTW, I cannot find any *.tpm file on my PC.

Comment: This is known to the MikTeX developer https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/144, see also https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/34. It should be fixed tomorrow.

Comment: I got the same error and could also not find the offending `tmp` file. I can only assume that MikTeX cleans up after itself and so the `.tmp` file is gone when you look for it.

Comment: @moewe OK, thanks a lot for the information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was an bug report meanwhile solved ...